# (C++) Function not declaring

Tags: c++, windows, sdl

I'm new to SDL, and I have a function bool init(). I've been learning SDL 2.0 from lazyfoot.net for a few days without a problem. I've been essentially copying their code, and today I tried to do my own. (EDIT: I know someone said I have an outdated header file. This is not the case, because I have been able to use SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED and other 2.0 features ever since I installed the library) For whatever reason, this won't work.

I'm using Windows 7 Starter, with Code::Blocks (MinGW as my compiler)

When I (try to) build and run, there is a red flag next to line 17, which is this.

```
bool init() {
```

Here is the entire source code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 500;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500;

bool init();
bool loadMedia();
void quit();

int time = 5000;

SDL_Window* window = NULL;
SDL_Surface* surface = NULL;
SDL_Surface* topImage = NULL;

bool init() {
    bool success = true;
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        success = false;
    }
    else{
        SDL_CreateWindow("My Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if(window == NULL) {
            std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
            success = false;
        }
    }
    return success;
}

bool loadMedia() {
    bool success = true;
    surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
    if(surface == NULL) {
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        success = false;
    }
    else {
        topImage = SDL_LoadBMP("image.bmp");
        if(topImage = NULL) {
            std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
            success = false;
        }
        else {
            SDL_BlitSurface(topImage, NULL, surface, NULL);
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
            SDL_Delay(time);
        }
    }
    return success;
}

void quit() {
    SDL_FreeSurface(topImage);
    topImage = NULL;

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = NULL;
    surface = NULL;

    SDL_Quit();
}

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
if(init() == true) {
    init();
        if(loadMedia() == true) {
            loadMedia();
        }
    }
quit();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try renaming init to something else. Maybe that name is already used somewhere in SDL.h

Comment: What does the error actually say?

Comment: There's no error. In Code::Blocks, there's a red box next to line 17 showing there's an error. I'm pretty new to Code::Blocks, so maybe there is a way to get the error and I'm just dumb, but I don't think that's the case

Comment: But what does the compiler output? I built your source in VS2013 and I get no errors.

Comment: It doesn't compile. If there's a bad spot in my code, it doesn't compile, nor does it create an exe file for me to manually open

Comment: And should use SDL_Texture instead of SDL_Surface with SDL 2.0.  SDL_Surface with blitting use CPU for graphic rendering and SDL_Texture use the GPU for graphic rendering which is more powerful for this !

Comment: Compare the lazyfoo codeblocks project files with yours to find the difference.  Normal causes are preprocessor definitions, the code generation, the input libraries and the location of the libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error:

```
error: 'SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED' was not declared in this scope
```

which means that your including headers for an older version of SDL. but `SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED` is defined in the SDL 2.0 version.

Just make sure to include the right headers which you can download them from the official library website: http://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't it. I should have been a bit more specific. (I just added information to my first paragraph). I have SDL 2.0, and SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED has always worked for me. My SDL files certainly aren't outdated

Comment: I don't get an error. It doesn't allow me to compile.

Comment: @user3317103 Could you print your screen and provide it?

Comment: Yeah. I'm away from my computer. I'll post it in an hour or so